# Resources$NotFoundException when trying to extract data from intent

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent

SO I am trying to create a contact manager module for a much bigger Android app, and I am using a Fragment in a ViewPager to display the contacts in a ListView. What I now want is the user to be able to edit the record by longClicking an item and selecting "Edit" from a List AlertDialog. The thing is, I want the new ContactEdit activity to have all the fields for the columns in the table filled with info of the particular record that was longClicked in the ListView of previous Fragment. I used the putExtra method to put in the Row ID of the record in the intent I am using to open the Activity. But on the other end, when I used the getIntent().getExtras().getInt() method, I was returned a android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException. Please take a look at the relevant code and error log and try to help out a learner bro here..

**ContactList.class**

```
package com.example.nikhil.test1;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;



public class ContactList extends Fragment {
    private SimpleCursorAdapter dataAdapter;
    private ContactsAdapter dbHelper;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.fragment_item_list, container, false);
        dbHelper = new ContactsAdapter(this.getActivity());
        dbHelper.open();
        Cursor cursor = dbHelper.getAllFriends();
        String[] columns = new String[] {
                ContactsAdapter.KEY_NAME, ContactsAdapter.KEY_Phone
        };
        int[] to = new int[] {
                R.id.name, R.id.phonenumber
        };
        dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                this.getActivity(), R.layout.contact_row,
                cursor,
                columns,
                to,
                0);
        ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);
        listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
        listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                builder.setTitle("Pick an action");
                builder.setItems(new String[]{"Edit","Delete","Activate Call Forwarding"}, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        if(which==0){
                        Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), ContactEdit.class);
                        i.putExtra("RowID",position);
                        startActivity(i);
                        }

                    }
                });
                AlertDialog alertDialog=builder.create();
                alertDialog.show();
                return true;
            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }


}
```

**ContactEdit.class**

```
package com.example.nikhil.test1;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import android.widget.EditText;


public class ContactEdit extends Activity {
    ContactsAdapter dbHelper;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_contact_edit);
        dbHelper = new ContactsAdapter(this);
        dbHelper.open();


        if(getIntent() != null) {
            Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
            EditText _Name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittextName);
            _Name.setText(extras.getInt("RowID"));
           /* int rowId = extras != null ? extras.getInt("RowID") : -1;
            Cursor cursor = dbHelper.getFriend(rowId);
            String name = cursor.getString(1);
            String mobile = cursor.getString(2);
            String home = cursor.getString(3);
            String address = cursor.getString(4);

            EditText _Name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittextName);
            _Name.setText(name);
            EditText _Mobile = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittextMobile);
            _Mobile.setText(mobile);
            EditText _Home = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittextHome);
            _Home.setText(home);
            EditText _Address = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittextAddress);
            _Address.setText(address);*/
        }
        else
        {
            EditText _Name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittextName);
            _Name.setText(" ");
            EditText _Mobile = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittextMobile);
            _Mobile.setText(" ");
            EditText _Home = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittextHome);
            _Home.setText(" ");
            EditText _Address = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittextAddress);
            _Address.setText(" ");
        }


    }



    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == android.R.id.home) {

            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

I put the actual intended code in comment so that I could see if even my Activity was able to extract the RowID from the intent
**logat error log**

```
06-18 15:49:45.676  18965-18965/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.nikhil.test1, PID: 18965
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.nikhil.test1/com.example.nikhil.test1.ContactEdit}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2335)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2397)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1310)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5268)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:902)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:697)
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0
            at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:305)
            at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4152)
            at com.example.nikhil.test1.ContactEdit.onCreate(ContactEdit.java:23)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6033)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2288)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2397)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1310)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5268)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:902)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:697)
```

Comment: Sow your activity_contact_edit.xml file

Comment: I think the problem is in this line : `_Name.setText(extras.getInt("RowID"));`

Comment: Try to change like this _Name.setText(String.valueOf(extras.getInt("RowID"))); and also change the putExtra() like i.putExtra("rowId",(int)position);

Comment: you have to convert int to string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this line may be causing the error:

```
  _Name.setText(extras.getInt("RowID"));
```

replace it with:

```
 _Name.setText(""+extras.getInt("RowID"));
```

just added "" to convert the integer to a String. Try it and tell us.